# transfer data with protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I try to decode weather api

this is my struct class weatherModal :

```
import Foundation

struct WeatherModel:Decodable{
    var main:Main?
}

struct Main:Decodable {
    var temp : Double?
    var feels_like : Double?
    var temp_min:Double?
    var temp_max:Double?
    var pressure , humidity: Int?

}
```

I am trying to learn protocols. So this is where a make api call manager class :

```
protocol WeatherManagerProtocol:AnyObject {
    func weatherData(weatherData:WeatherModel)
}
class WeatherManager{
    var weather : WeatherModel?
    
    weak var delegate :WeatherManagerProtocol?
    
    public func callWeather(city:String) {
    
        let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(city)&appid=1234"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err!.localizedDescription)          
            } else {
                do {
                    self.weather = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherModel.self, from: data!)
                    self.delegate?.weatherData(weatherData: self.weather!)
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }          
        }.resume()    
    }
}
```

In my `ViewController` what I want to do is user write city name on `textfield` and If user clicked the process button print the information about weather.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var weatherManager = WeatherManager()
    var data : WeatherModel?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        weatherManager.delegate = self
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func processButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        if textField.text != "" {
           weatherManager.callWeather(city: textField.text ?? "nil")
           print(data?.main?.humidity) // it print nil
            
        } else{
           print("empty")
        }
    }

    extension ViewController: WeatherManagerProtocol{
        func weatherData(weatherData: WeatherModel) {
            self.data = weatherData
            print(self.data.main)
            // in here I can show my data
    }
}
```

When I clicked process button it always print nil. Why ? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I improved your code formatting (indentation, Xcode can do this for you automatically), for future questions make sure you do the same, this way your code will be easier to read for all of us and you'll get more, faster and better answers

Comment: Asynchronous methods are like calling to order a pizza. You don't have a pizza once you're done your phone call. You *might* get a pizza, some point in the future.

Comment: Thank you,I will pay attention.

Answer (score 2):

You seem not to understand how your own code is supposed to work. The whole idea of the protocol-and-delegate pattern you've set up is that the "signal" round-trips thru the weather manager on a path like this:

1. You (the ViewController) say `weatherManager.callWeather`
2. The weather manager does some networking.
3. The weather manager calls its own delegate's `weatherData`.
4. You (the ViewController) *are* that delegate, so your `weatherData` is called and that is where you can `print`.

So that is the signal path:

```
@IBAction func processButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    weatherManager.callWeather(city: textField.text ?? "nil") // < TO wm
}
func weatherData(weatherData: WeatherModel) { // < FROM wm
    // can print `weatherData` here
}
```

You cannot short circuit this path by trying to print the weather data anywhere else. Stay on the path. You cannot turn this into a "linear" simple path; it is *asynchronous*.

If you *do* want it to look more like a "linear" simple path, use a *completion handler* instead of a delegate callback. That's what I do in my version of this same experiment, so my view controller code looks like this:

```
self.jsonTalker.fetchJSON(zip:self.currentZip) { result in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // and now `result` contains the weather data, or an error
```

Even better, use the Combine framework (or wait until Swift 6 implements async/await).

Comment: I should add: a completion handler would be a much better architecture than your protocol-and-delegate, because what if the user changes the text field taps the button twice in quick succession? You can get all out of sync: your `weatherData` is called but you have no way of knowing what city that corresponds to.

Answer (score 0):

You call to `weatherManager.callWeather` that start `URLSession.shared.dataTask`. the task is executed asynchronously, but `callWeather` return immediately. So, when you print `data?.main?.humidity`, the task did not finish yet, and `data` is still `nil`. After the task finish, you call `weatherData` and assign the response to `data`.